# Cell value increasing by 1 when value in another cell reaches 100

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, split, decimal

In Google Sheets is it possible to have the value in cell `A1` to increase by 1 when the value in `B1` reaches 100 and also changing the value in `B1` to -100?

So for example, "120" in `B1` would change the value of `A1` to "1" and change the value of `B1` to "20".

Basically, I am looking to use the value of `A1` as a whole number and the value in `B1` as the decimal place but with a max of 99 on the decimal place.

Update following request for same but with varying max decimal numbers:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/193Vbg9Dm4qDjIx4PNcmTOkMyPLdDaAr5-HaFkD1V2Eg/edit?usp=sharing

Columns A-C are input columns
Columns F-I are to work out the totals of the input columns for the relevant people and then to concatenate as a decimal figure
Columns K-N are updated totals using @player0's formula based on the max decimal place being 99 before it increases the whole number by 1 at 100.

So using the 44.120 total as an example, using decimal maximums of 50, 80 & 90 for when the whole number is changed:
For 50 - 44.120 would become 46.20
For 80 - 44.120 would become 45.40
For 90 - 44.120 would become 45.30

Comment: sounds like an xyproblem:  http://xyproblem.info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE("0000"&A1:A6, "(.+)(.{2})$", "$1×$2"), "×"))
```

[image]

Comment: That seems to work @player0 - I may have a requirement to set similar up but where the decimal only goes to 49, 79 & 89 with the whole number changing at 50, 80 & 90 respectively. I've had a play around with your formula to see if it can simply be updated to suit the different values but can't seem to find a way - is this possible?

Comment: @The_Train can you share a copy of your sheet with examples of desired results within your requirements of 49,79,89/50/80,90. its hard to guess how you wish it

Comment: I've added it to the original post along with further detail - hoping it makes sense

Comment: @The_Train see this if its it: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UBkKRLv-FYv8qW7HYGBiv3GSDsOJUPsRffFmDAbGEC8/edit#gid=0

Comment: I can see the logic in that but the final outcomes on all but the 100 are incorrect. Using the 80 as an example on the 44.120 line - it would be a case of 80 from the 120 would create 1 which would be added to the 44, leaving 40 from the 120 which would become the new decimal, leaving a final figure of 45.40

Comment: @The_Train see now: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UBkKRLv-FYv8qW7HYGBiv3GSDsOJUPsRffFmDAbGEC8/edit#gid=2061990683

Answer (score 0):

What want is not 100% able to be completed, but this is:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 75 | 175 |
| 0 | 75 | 75 |
| `=IF(C1>100, LEFT(C1,1), "0")` | `=IF(C1>100, RIGHT(C1, 2), C1)` | Input Number Here... |